# Good implementation of bias units in neural network

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, neural-network, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I am learning about neural network and in the process, I have implemented few fully connected nets. I usually add a `column bias units`(1s) in the input marix and an `extra row of weights` in weight matrix because that's how I learned to implement neural nets after taking an online course but in many implementations on github I have found that it can also be implemented without inserting bias units in the matrix but instead it can be added separately : `XW + b` , where b is bias unit .

I don't understand how it works. It seems like a better  and more efficient implementation but I don't understand it. For instance , consider the following example:

```
        1 2 3 4       0.5 0.5
   X =  1 4 5 6    W= 2   3     X*W = [4x2 matrix] 
        1 8 9 5       5   8
                      2   3
```

`The first column in X is bias unit and so is the first row in W`

But if the same is written without directly inserting the bias column but by adding it separately it becomes:

```
       2 3 4       2 3
   X=  4 5 6    W= 5 8    b = 0.5 0.5    X*W = [3x2 matrix]
       8 9 5       2 3
```

It can be clearly seen that `X*W+b` from the second expression is not equal to first expression. And furthermore b, a `1x2 matrix` cannot be added to `X*W` which is `3x2 matrix`.

So, how can i implement biases using the second method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The illustrated methods are the same.

most important:

> weights can only assume values between -1 and 1.

---

note: the first example will give a 3x2 matrix too.

```
      1 2 3 4           0.5 0.5          27.5  42.5
 X =  1 4 5 6        W= 2   3      X*W = 45.5  70.5
      1 8 9 5           5   8            71.5  111.5                                    
                        2   3
```

In the last matrix each row is a set of inputs and each column a neuron.

---

The illustrated methods are the same:
Add the bias later is not a problem.

taking the second example:

```
       |27  42 |            |27 42 |   |0.5 0.5|
 X*W = |45  70 |    X*W+b = |45 70 | + |0.5 0.5| : Same Result.
       |71  111|            |71 111|   |0.5 0.5|
```

### If The problem is here:

taking the formula at the link below:
[Feed_Forward formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0FKH.png)

It assume a neural network whit 1 input, 1 hidden and 1 output neurons and it not involves a product of matrices. It's a feedforward passage:

sumH1 = I x w1 + b x wb;

note:(b x wb = 1 x wb = wb).

This passage is than coded at "implementation" paragrafe:

```
z1 = x.dot(W1) + b1
a1 = np.tanh(z1)
z2 = a1.dot(W2) + b2
```

### Or here:

[B belonging to R^500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcS13.png)

Here he make an hypothetic example whit 2 Input, 500 Hidden and 2 Output neurons, where says that w1 is one of the 2x500 connections between I and H, b1 is one of the 500 bias of H, w2 is one of the 2x500 connections between H and O, b2, is one of the 2 bias of O.

### To sum up

You can do the feed_forward passage using matrices but you have to add the bias for each connection. The first example you showed is the simplest way. It's clear
that if you choose the second one you can not do the product of the 1xN matrice whit the 3x2. But you can add the bias addition when you call the activation function:

```
a1 = tanH(z1 + b[1]);
```

> none of the two is a better or more efficient implementation than other.

---

in the second example you are splitting that matix in 2 parts:

```
I*W :matix[3x4]     and    b:vector[3] = { 1, 1 , 1 }
```

in this case you need to add the bias at each hidden neuron too.
in your first example you have directly added the bias where:
`matrix[0][0] = 1 x 0.5 + 2 x 2 + 3 x 5 ecc..`

note:`matrix[0][0] = sumH1;`

in the second one you add the bias later where:`matrix[0][0] = 2 x 2 + 3 x 5 ecc..` and `sumH1 = matrix[0][0] + B[0]`

note: whit "B" we intend the weights of B; B=1.

maybe whit the second example the code will result a little more ordered. nothing more. no significative changes in computer performance or memory occupation.

Comment: Yeah got it. But this means that the dimension of bais should be same as the resultant matrix after multiplying input and weights but many articles state that is weight matrix is MxN then bias should be 1xN matrix.

Comment: Can you please link some of these articles for clarification?

Comment: http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/implementing-a-neural-network-from-scratch/ go to "how our networks make predictions" section and check the dimension of b1

Comment: One more thing. Why none of the two is a better or more efficient implementation than other ? Clearly in the first implementation we need to insert a column of 1s in the matrices but in the second one we just need to add another matrix.